# how to filter with match path only?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to filter only the sub-routes based on index path.

In the following example, everything works fine but we don't expect any routes belonging to `/ab` in the output.

```
function getRoutes(path: string, routerData) {
    return Object.keys(routerData).filter(routePath => {
        console.log('routePath', routePath.indexOf(path));
        return routePath.indexOf(path) === 0 && routePath !== path;
    });
}

routerData = {
 ['/a']: {},
  ['/a/1]: {},
  ['/a/2]: {},
  ['/b/1]: {},
 ['/b/2]: {},
 ['/ab/2/1]: {},
}
```

Expecting result

```
 const result = ['/a/1', '/a/2'];
        expect(getRoutes('/a', routerData).map(item => item.path)).toEqual(result);

 Expected value to equal:

  ["/a/1", "/a/2"]
Received:
  ["/a/1", "/a/2", "/ab/2/1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function matches all routes that start with `/a` and are not limited to `/a`. So you get `/a1` too.

To avoid that, you need to check all routes that start with `/a/` instead:

```
function getRoutes(path: string, routerData) {
    if (path[path.length-1] !== '/')
        path += '/'; // Add a '/' to exclude incomplete paths
    return Object.keys(routerData).filter(routePath => {
        console.log('routePath', routePath.indexOf(path));
        return routePath.indexOf(path) === 0; // This becomes useless: && routePath !== path;
    });
}
```